# Can't see changes in main.css in Google Chrome, Internet Explorer or Firefox

Tags: html, css

I added the `background-image` and `background-repeat` but I can't see any changes when I refresh.  But if I make the change in developer tools I see the images immediately.  I'm using a template called Landed from pixelarity.com.

```
body.landing #header {
        background: transparent;
        background-image: url("/images/protintlogo3.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        box-shadow: none;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

As I say it does this in 3 different browsers so I'm thinking it must have something to do with the website.  It's a Godaddy Econmomy Linux Hosting site.

Comment: is the correct CSS-File loaded, no cached version? (you can check it with developer-tools)

Comment: have you cleared the browser cache?

Comment: I have cleared the cache in all 3 browsers several times.  I'm using UltraEdit to modify html and css files.  I've made changes tried refreshing to no avail so I close the file from the editor and reopened and it is the correct file and I also looked at it on the Godaddy File Manager and the changes are there.

Comment: Do you have alternate stylesheets or is any rule overriding another?!

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: If I wait long enough the changes will finally make it to the page, which makes me think it's some sort of a caching problem but according to Godaddy support they have no caching on the hosting and three different browswers are doing the same thing.